# change the timezone of datetimeoffset

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a `DateTimeOffset` variable whose value is 11-11-1989 **16:00:00 +03:30**.
I can call `ToLocalTime()` method on it and it shows 11-11-1989 **18:00:00 +05:30**. (I am in India :p)

I am looking for something like this:
`variable1.ToOffset(<timespan>)`

If I give this function a `timespan` of 3 hours, It should return me 11-11-1989 **19:00:00 +06:30**.

I tried to change the offset, but offset property is read-only. Does anyone know any workaround for this ?

Comment: What about AddHours() of DateTimeOffset? Or Add(Timespan)?

Comment: There is a built in function exactly as described in my question. The name of function is also same!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is stupid. But there **is** a function named `ToOffset` and it takes `timespan` as input parameter!

Answer (score 12):

For future readers:
I've had a `DateTimeOffset` that was parsed without timezone. 
So to change the timezone only, without affecting the actual time you have to subtract the timespan again as in underlying code.

e.g. `2018-03-27T11:00:00 +00:00 => 2018-03-27T11:00:00 +02:00`

```
static DateTimeOffset ChangeUtcToCest(DateTimeOffset original)
{
    TimeZoneInfo cetInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
    DateTimeOffset cetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(original, cetInfo);
    return original
        .Subtract(cetTime.Offset)
        .ToOffset(cetTime.Offset);
}
```

Comment: You should cache `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time")` in a `static readonly` field for performance.

Comment: Thanks, Sam Sengers. This is working fine for me. Dai, yes I stored it all timezone (Windows/Linux).