# How to change the Timzone of a ZonedDateTime without converting the time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetimeoffset, nodatime

I have a `ZonedDateTime` which I have created using a `DateTimeOffset` and a timezone id (string), and I also have a `DateTimeZone`.

The particular case I have is that I need to change the `Zone` of the ZonedDateTime without actually converting the time (i.e. i have 18:00 UTC-4:00, i want to change this to 18:00 UTC-8 **without** converting the 18:00 accordingly)

The only pertinent function I'm finding is `.WithZone(DateTimeZone)` but this seems to convert my time based on the provided zone

How can I change the "timezone" of my ZonedDateTime without converting the time?

EDIT i found a solution that seems to work:

```
private DateTimeOffset myFunction(DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset, string timeZoneId) {
    // get the DateTimeZone (i.e. Etc/GMT)
    DateTimeZone timezone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneId];

    // create a new DTO with the previous date/time values, but with the DateTimeZone Offset
    var newDTO = new DateTimeOffset(dateTimeOffset.DateTime, timezone.GetUtcOffset(SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant()).ToTimeSpan());

    // create a ZonedDateTime based on the new DTO
    var nodaDTO = ZonedDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(newDTO);

    // the correct datetime in the correct zone
    var finalProduct = nodaDTO.WithZone(timezone);

    return finalProduct.ToDateTimeOffset();
}
```

Comment: Please could you give some sample code of what you're doing? It sounds fairly odd at the moment - there may be a better way of approaching the bigger problem you're trying to solve. (You can always get the `LocalDateTime` of the `ZonedDateTime`, then use `InZone` on that... but it's an odd thing to do here. You're basically saying that the instant being represented in the original `ZonedDateTime` should be ignored. That makes me nervous at least. It's possible you have an exceptional reason - but I'd be interested to hear it.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe i found a solution - i've updated my question to include my possible solution code

Comment: You've edited the question, but it still doesn't really help us know what you're trying to achieve. I'm sure it'll be easy to make it *much* simpler than this, once we have more of an idea of what you're trying to accomplish - sample input and expected output would be really useful here. (Again, it's quite odd to have a `DateTimeOffset`, but want to ignore the offset of it entirely...)

Comment: @JonSkeet i don't really know how else to word it, the case I have is that my Date/Time is correct but my Timezone/Offset is incorrect, so i want to change the Timezone/Offset of my datetimeoffset without converting the datetime to be in that zone. Now that i think of it, i believe `newDTO` is exactly what i need and the rest of my steps are useless

Comment: Your code is very broken, I believe - you're assuming that the offset you want is off the *current* offset in that time zone. What if you're receiving a winter DTO and it's currently summer? It feels like you really want `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimeOffset.DateTime).InZoneLeniently(zone)` - but that "leniently" part is something you need to think about carefully. What do you want to do if the date/time is ambiguous in the given time zone, or skipped? How come you've got an incorrect `DateTimeOffset` to start with? Can you fix the upstream problem that causes that instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet you're correct. it appears as though i'm trying to solve a problem in the wrong place. I've looked at where the original `DateTimeOffset` is being created (it is created from a CRON expression string) and it is created in the wrong offset (always 0 Offset) despite having access to both the Offset and the TimeZoneId - I will fix the problem at the source, i don't need any of the code i provided

Comment: Glad I was able to steer it in a helpful direction, even if it means I can't display Noda Time expertise in an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the desire to do this normally indicates something broken further upstream - and if you can fix it there, you should.

If you end up in a situation with a `DateTimeOffset` where the local part is definitely correct but the offset isn't, and you really can't fix the data earlier, then you'll need to find the correct UTC offset for that local time. It's important to note that the local time may be ambiguous (if it occurs during a "fall back" transition) or skipped (if it occurs during a "spring forward" transition), and you should work out what to do in that situation.

You can use `DateTimeZone.MapLocal` for that:

```cs
private DateTimeOffset myFunction(DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset, string timeZoneId)
{
    var unspecifiedDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeOffset.DateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneId];
    var local = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(unspecifiedDateTime);
    ZoneLocalMapping mapping = zone.MapLocal(local);
    // Read documentation for details of this; you can easily detect the
    // unambiguous/ambiguous/skipped cases here. You should decide what to do with them.
    ZoneInterval mappedInterval = mapping.EarlyInterval;
    TimeSpan bclOffset = mappedInterval.WallOffset.ToTimeSpan();
    return new DateTimeOff(unspecifiedDateTime, bclOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you create an new `DateTimeOffset` variable with the new timezone offset? after all your existing `ZonedDateTime` value just represent one "true" time across global, update the offset will update the time which is correct if we're thinking about time concept.

Otherwise you could create a new DateTimeOffset in the target timezone then use the Subtract method to modify your existing time. it will return a new DateTimeOffset value.
Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49518361/8191918